# Python Pandas time series groupby not behaving as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

`df.head()`
[image]
`df.dtypes`

[image]

`df.index.dtype`

[image]

The problem is resampling the data and getting correct results on different time periods.

e.g:

```
# count frame drops per second - works correctly
df.to_period(freq='S').groupby('ts')['frame_drop_issue'].sum()
```

[image]

```
# count frame drops per minute - works correctly
df.to_period(freq='T').groupby('ts')['frame_drop_issue'].sum()
```

[image]

But, if I try to aggregate by a period of 2 seconds, I get wrong results (similar as one second result)

```
# count frame drops per 2 seconds- wrong result
df.to_period(freq='2S').groupby('ts')['frame_drop_issue'].sum()
```

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you try with `resample`?

Comment: please post code and data, not images of such

Comment: try: `df.resample('2S')['frame_drop_issue'].sum()`

Comment: this worked, thanks. Do you understand why this worked and not to_period?
(i can't mark a comment as a response, so if you want to move it to the response i will mark it as the resolution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_period` probably doesn't work with multiples of frequency. It's still an open issue 
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14070. 
Instead you can use `resample`.

```
df.resample('2S')['frame_drop_issue'].sum()
```